# Opencv/c++ - Record live video in thread, image processing in another thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, video

I am hoping to write a program that records a live video from a webcam at a constant frame-rate, while performing image processing between video recording.

The image processing algorithm will take longer than the frame rate, so the video recording would take priority.

I am guessing that the answer is threading, although I am new to this concept. Is this achievable using threading? What might a template look like for this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Presumably, the webcam client will be mostly blocked while receiving the images so, yes, I assume that it would be reasonable to thread off the processing but, without some clearer detail of the protocol/s used, it's difficult to come up with much except 'use a producer-consumer queue to communicate image-units frim the webcam-client thread to the image-processing thread'.

Answer (score 0):

You could have  a look at this:

https://code.google.com/p/qt-opencv-multithreaded/

Is is done in Qt thread, but I think Qt thread is very easy to understand:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/thread-basics.html